# shortest odds in a top-class horse race

Tags: betting, horse-racing

In his final non-walkover race, the 150 Guineas at Newmarket in 1770, the undefeated Eclipse was offered odds of 1/70. These odds seem remarkable. Are there prominent examples of shorter odds in top-class horse-racing? Maybe in more recent races?

Comment: In horse races in the states, a person betting on the winning horse is guaranteed to win 10 cents on the dollar. So the shortest odds, base on the payout, is 1/10. The actual odds, of course, are just based on the actual money bet.  What would the odds be if everyone bet on the same horse?

Answer (score 1):

The lowest I could find was Man o' War from 1920, winning with 1/100 odds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_o%27_War

> Just ten days later, Man o' War returned in the Stuyvesant Handicap
>   which he won easily against only one rival. His odds of 1 to 100 were
>   believed to be the lowest ever offered in an American horserace